# pt-achive of percona is taking up too much CPU and database connections

Tags: mysql, rds, percona

I am archiving my RDS MySQL database to a secondary database using pt-archival from percona but during the archival activity the CPU and DB connections of the database increases. The archival activity consists of deleting data from the main database and copying it to the secondary database. Is there some way this can be reduced since this is a production database.

The pt-archive command is -

```
pt-archiver --source h=source-database.com,u=username,p=password,D=dbName,t=tableName --where "creation_time< current_date - interval 30 day" --dest h=dest-database.com,u=username,p=password  --limit 1000 --txn-size 1000 --progress 1000 --optimize=s
```

Comment: Ask Percona if you should be doing this during prime time, please.

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve your *current* problem.  You should consider a schema change that will prevent this problem *recurring*.

The gist is to `PARTITION BY RANGE(...)` the main table, then use `DROP PARTITION` (virtually instant) and `REORGANIZE PARTITION` (also fast).

Discussion on time-series partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

(Caveat:  You will need some downtime and/or pt-online-schema-change to partition your table, plus code and `INDEX` changes.)

More on taming big deletes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig